# Installing Python libraries (difflib and pygments)

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Linux and I need to install difflib and pygments python libraries to my computer. What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For pygments-

```
pip install Pygments
```

For difflib-

```
apt-get install npm
npm install difflib
```